# How many cannonballs would it take to go from 70-99 slayer in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

With 99 range and 99 defence, approximately how many cannonballs would it take to go from 70-99 slayer if one used cannon alone except where it can't be used?

Answer (score 11):

To get from level 70 to level 99 takes 12,960,804 experience. To get that much slayer experience, you must deal approximately that much damage to NPCs. The number of cannonballs you will need for this depends on your average damage per cannonball. Your average damage in turn depends on your range level, your equipment, and the monsters you are fighting. If we estimate an average damage of 200 for example it will get 20 slayer exp, then you will need about 648,040 cannonballs.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.